# Filter divs based on dropdown select - is there an easy way?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a grid made up of divs that have wordpress page IDs as classes, they also have the common class 'set'.

I have a dropdown select that contain each page as an `<option>` with the page ID as the value.

I want to be able to select a page title in the dropdown menu, and have any corresponding div in the grid with the class 'patient-`pageID`' only to be visible, and all others hidden.

```
$('#filterPatient_dropdown').change(function() {
    var patientID = $("#filterPatient_dropdown option:selected").val();
    $('.set').hide();
    if ($(this).val() == 'patient'+patientID) {
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

This just hides all the divs when I click on an option.

How can I perform a simple yet effective filter where I click on an option, where the value is the page ID, and it finds the matching class of all divs and only shows these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this one?

```
$('#filterPatient_dropdown').change(function() {
    var patientID = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    $('.set').hide();
    $('div.patient-'+patientID).show();
});
```

Comment: Hey, I think this is going to be the accepted answer, as this worked straight out of the box. I think maybe the usage of a variable made it work.

Comment: Using variables has got nothing to do with it, if it were `$(this).find("option:selected").val()` instead of `patientID`, it would have worked just the same :)

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `.show()` on `$(this)`, which in this case is the dropdown and not the div. Try using `$('.patient-' + patientID).show();`

Comment: Hmm trying something along those lines, with $('.set').hide(); $('.patient-' + this).show(); as the only things within the change function, and all the divs are hiding. The show action doesn't seem to be getting hit.

Comment: Try it with `$('.patient-' + $(this).val()).show();`